# How to call a function during *ngFor iteration in angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-directive, ngfor

I have scenario where I am showing items based on view mode. So I want to change viewMode during every iteration but I can't. Can anyone have any idea? Let me know. Thanks

```
<div *ngFor="let pr of d.data; viewMode();"> 
// rendering content according to viewMode
```

Comment: You're not making sense: Why does "rendering according to" view mode require "changing" it?

Comment: basically i am creating timeline view from certian data. So i want that everyIteration i want to show items on left side then right side.....aw viewMode that i want to set as left-view and right-view and based on this value i am using classBinding to apply my styles! @meriton

Comment: you can use ngIf or ngSwitch and based on view load the content

Comment: @Amrit for ngIf I need expression. for that i declare property in component. and want to call a function for toggling that property value!

Answer (score 0):

There's a workaround.

**Scenario 1:** If you pass viewMode inside your component

```
<div *ngFor="let pr of d.data; let i = index;">
    <your-component [viewMode]="i % 2 === 0 ? viewMode1 : viewMode2" *ngIf="i % 2 === 0">
    </your-component>
</div>
```

**Scenario 2:** If you want to render a different component according to viewMode

```
<div *ngFor="let pr of d.data; let i = index;">
    <your-component1 *ngIf="i % 2 === 0"><!--According to first viewMode-->
    </your-component1>
    <your-component2 *ngIf="i % 2 === 1"><!--According to second viewMode-->
    </your-component2>
</div>
```

**Note:** Here `i % 2 === 0` will check odd/event. So, your toggling will work this way.

Comment: You can also alias `odd` or `even` boolean values to local variable to avoid the modulo operations. e.g. `<li *ngFor="let user of users; even as isEven">`

Comment: Didn't know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can alias odd or even boolean values to local variable to avoid the modulo operations. e.g. `<li *ngFor="let user of users; even as isEven">`

@answered according to https://stackoverflow.com/users/13676960/hopey-one
Thanks @Hopey One